# linq lambda expression for sql contains

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I am using a generic repository, like this:

```
 itemsList = (from myrow in UoW.FileRepository.Get()
 select new FileModel()
 {record_id = myrow.type_id,
  descr = myrow.descr}).ToList();});
```

And this is the Get method:

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        //  _aQuery = _theDbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        IEnumerable<TEntity> query = _aQuery;
        return query;
    }
```

How would I implement a generic linq lambda expression if I wanted to create a similar query to search for a particular string in a particular field?  In my viewmodel I would like to call something like:

```
     from myrow in UoW.FileRepository.Srch(nameofFieldToSearch, searchString).
```

The query would look something like this?

```
   public IEnumerable<TEntity> Srch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> srchList = _aQuery.ToList();
        return srchList.Where(????);

    }
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

EDIT-----------------------
I have all my queries like Get and Srch in a general repository class and for now just need to know how to declare the query in the repository class and how to call it with the search string from my viewmodel.  I am not sure if there is a consensus as to where/when to materialize and compile?  I saw another discussion http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/01/10/More-on-Expression-vs-Func-with-Entity-Framework.aspx and I quote from it below to inquire whether that is the same approach being suggested here?  Thank you again.

> "The profiler told us that LoadMyEntities was being called many, many times and it was taking a large fraction of our CPU time. The simple change below solved the problem. Can you guess why?"

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> LoadMyEntities(Func<MyEntity, bool> predicate)
{return Context.MyEntities.Where(predicate);}
```

> "The parameter is now a Func<> instead of an Expression>. The reason this makes a difference is that a predicate that's in the form of an Expression is passed to SQL server, but a predicate that's passed as a Func is not. Normally, you'd want SQL Server to do as much for you as possible, and an Expression would be the right choice, but in this case we'd like to pre-load the entire table in the context -- which is exactly what a Func will do.

1. The Where extension method has two flavors. One extends IQueryable and takes an Expression parameter. The other extends IEnumerable and takes a Func.
2. Because 'predicate' is now a Func, the Where that extends IEnumerable is used.
3. The Entity Framework's fluent interface for constructing SQL queries is based on IQueryables, not IEnumerables. Therefore, the fluency stops just before the Where. The part of the statement that gets passed to the Entity Framework is just Context.MyEntities.
4. Context.MyEntities therefore returns the entire table to the context.
5. The entire table is now filtered with the predicate, and the value we really want is returned.
6. The next time the method is called, the Entity Framework realizes that the record we want is already in the context. (In my case, we were querying by the primary key, and EF is apparently smart enough to know that if there's a record in the context with that ID, it won't find an additional such record in the database.) Since we don't go out to SQL Server, we save lots of time. Obviously there are occasions when you would not want this, but in our case it was exactly what we wanted. The table was relatively small, and the same context was queried hundreds of times.

> In the original version, the predicate was an Expression, so the compiler used the Where that extends IQueryable. The predicate was thus passed to SQL Server, which dutifully returned just one row to the context. The next time we called LoadMyEntities, Entity Framework had to call SQL Server again."

Comment: Look at dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a simple implementation using the Expression trees. Following is the complete solution:

Method to fetch the Expression for `Srch` method:

```
Public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SrchExpression(string nameofFieldToSearch, string searchString)
{
  var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "obj");

  var memberExpression = Expression.Property(typeof(string), nameofFieldToSearch)

 // Calls Extension method created underneath
 var filtersMethodInfo = typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

 var filtersConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(searchString, typeof(string));

 var finalExpression = Expression.Call(null, filtersMethodInfo, memberExpression, filtersConstantExpression)

 return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(finalExpression, parameterType)
}
```

// Create a String extension method for Contains

```
public static class StringExtensions
{        
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string searchString)
    {
        return source?.IndexOf(subString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Now your `Srch` method shall look like:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Srch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
    Func<TEntity, bool>> func = expression.Compile();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> srchList = _aQuery.Where(o => func(o));
    return srchList;
}
```

Comment: How about `_aQuery.Where(expression).ToList()` The `ToList()` will materialize the query. How about adding the filter condition before materializing

Comment: That will make it slow, since it will compile every time, compilation is important operation, which shall not be repeated for every value in the IEnumerable

Comment: if database contain 1000 records materializing will take more time than compilation

Comment: Ok we are talking about different things, I have copied OP's code where he has made it ToList() and then applied Where, but we can directly apply, though somewhere it needs to materialize. Check the edit, though Compilation of expression in advance is still important for any kind of data

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I understand lambdas, expressions & func conceptually, but implementing it is my problem.  I saw somewhere else an approach and was wondering how the suggestions here compared to that approach.

Comment: @harpagornis My solution is complete and you can directly implement it. It contains everything you need to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you both, but I don't see the function call I would execute in my viewmodel to actually load the record objects?  It would analogous to Get(), such as: itemsList = (from myrow in UoW.FileRepository.Srch()  What Goes Here?

Comment: Also, if it matters, the repositories are strongly typed.  I create GenericRepository<AddressFile>, GenericRepository<PhoneNumberFile>, etc.

Comment: @harpagornis you don't see what you need, because you don't understand the technology that you are trying to use, though i can further spoon feed, but it would be a disservice to you, would not help in learning at all

Comment: No it doesn't matter if the repositories are typed in current case using Expression trees, it will work the same way

Comment: Er uh yeah, I do understand the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [msdn](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) repository pattern

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

> This will provide more complete Generic `Get` method.

For search you could Try

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GlobalSearch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
   return Get(expression);
}
```

In `DataProvider` you could try something like this

*Note* This is not may be exact implementation, but will give you basic idea, how to invoke.

```
public List<Users> Search(List<string> userList)
{
      Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression = x=>UserList.Contains(x.UserName);

      return GlobalSearch(expression);

}
```

[Example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Repository-Pattern-in-MVC5-0bf41cd0) of Repository pattern

Comment: Repository pattern is good but where did you create the Filter Expression, which is the main challenge for OP

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have updated the answer, i think this may have basic idea about how to invoke

Comment: this would still not help since OP doesn't have a typed entity as expected to get the x.UserName, Column name is available as a string